# Image rotation memory error

Tags: c#, asp.net, image

I'm using a simple `Image.RotateFlip()` method in `C#` but I keep getting an error saying "Out of memory." I ran it through a profiler and found out it's happening on System.Drawing.Image.FromFile();

Here's my code:

```
 protected void rotatePic(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ImageButton img = sender as ImageButton;
        string url = img.ImageUrl.Split('?')[0];

        System.Drawing.Image pic = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(Server.MapPath(url));
        pic.RotateFlip(System.Drawing.RotateFlipType.Rotate270FlipNone);
        pic.Save(Server.MapPath(url));
        pic.Dispose();
        img.ImageUrl = img.ImageUrl + "?" + DateTime.Now.ToString();
    }
```

Comment: how big is the image?

Comment: @Quibblesome they always vary but the biggest is under 4MB.

Comment: Well chances are the OOM is for real. That is you're running OOM, especially if Ed S is correct and you're not disposing of images correctly. The best way to find out (if its not obvious in code) is to attach the .NET Memory profiler and examine the heap. While I've experienced incorrect OOM's in System.Drawing before they're typically on mobile devices with poorly customised operating systems. So profile it and triple check your code before thinking the API might be amiss.

Comment: Yes, a good memory profiler make your life much easier when you encounter OOM situations.  I like RedGate ANTS profiler.  It has a free trial.

Comment: I'll try it to use that.

Comment: please view the edited version

Answer (score 3):

Your question lacks a lot of relevant information.  First; how large is the image.  Second, how is this code being called.  Is it being called often?  When are you calling `Dispose()` on `pic`?  [System.Drawing.Image](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.image.aspx) implements `IDisposable`, so your code should (probably) look like this:

```
using(var pic = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(Server.MapPath(url)))
{
    pic.RotateFlip(System.Drawing.RotateFlipType.Rotate270FlipNone);
    pic.Save(Server.MapPath(url));
}
```

Comment: @StørmShadøws: Still didn't answer these questions: *"First; how large is the image. Second, how is this code being called."*  Also, use a `using` statement. If `RotateFlip` or `Save` throw you don't call `Dispose()`.

Comment: The image sizes vary since they're uploaded to the server. The max size of the images are 4MB. The code is being called on a image click.

Comment: @StørmShadøws: Ok, well does this happen more often with certain images?  Are you sure this code isn't being called too often?  Do you have *any* helpful information gleaned through the debugging you have already performed?

Comment: It's being called extremely rarely, the odds of it being called is 1 in 250 pictures.

Comment: I tried the above code and I still got this error, even with pic.Dispose();

Comment: @StørmShadøws - Is 4MB the size of the image on disk?  In memory, the images will be uncompressed and will take more memory.  What are the images dimensions and bit depth?

Comment: @StørmShadøws.  Yes, as chris says, image data size is `width * height * depth`.  So a 100 x 100 image using 3 bytes per pixel == 100 * 100 * 3 == 3000 bytes == 2.93MB.  I could have a huge image with one color in it which would probably compress down to nothing on disk, but be *huge* when represented in raw form as a `Bitmap` in memory.

Comment: @StørmShadøws: I would use a profiler.  All this guessing is wasting time at this point, and I don't have any more advice to offer given the information you've provided.

Comment: I'll try using the profiler. But does it help that this is only happening server side?

Comment: @StørmShadøws: You need to run the profiler on the server, i.e., where the exception is actually thrown...

Answer (score 0):

If you are doing it several times you should not forget to Dispose() your images.

Comment: I added that, but the odds of this being called is 1 in every 250 images. So I'm sure that's not the problem.